# How to change a string into a specific place?

Tags: bash

Hello everyone I am working with a text that looks as follows:

```
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|Archive" "Yes"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCharSet" "13A"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCommAgreeID" ""
"AF|AFFSDFSFA13A13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo" "fsdfs"
```

I would like to replace some strings in the text in particular to change this value 13A to 14B, in the line:

```
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCharSet" "13A"
```

and my desired output would be:

```
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCharSet" "14B"
```

I tried:

```
sed "s/13A/14B/g" test.txt > test2.txt
```

and I got:

```
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|Archive" "Yes"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCharSet" "14B"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCommAgreeID" ""
"AF|AFFSDFSFA14B13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo" "fsdfs"
```

The command work well but the problem is that is also affecting lines that match with the string like:

```
"AF|AFFSDFSFA13A13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
```

And changes it to:

```
"AF|AFFSDFSFA14B13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
```

but I don´t want it, I just want to affect the value that is within the quotes, I would like to obtain this output:

```
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|Archive" "Yes"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCharSet" "14B"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFCommAgreeID" ""
"AF|AFFSDFSFA13A13|AFFICCheckCtlNo" "fsdf"
"AF|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFICLstRcvdCtlNo" "fsdfs"
```

I would like to appreciate any suggestion of how to achieve this result.

Comment: Also, if you know the exact line number where the text to change is located, you may specify it before sed's 's' command to restrict sed to edit that line only. I find it useful when seding configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with quotes?

```
sed 's/"13A"/"14B"/g' test.txt > test2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.